# How can I process the new content in a text box after the onkeydown event?

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

I have a text input :

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="processText(this)" />
```

I have a processing function :

```
function processText(sender)
{
  console.log(sender.value);
  /// processing....
}
```

But then I check my value, its content hasn't been updated yet.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onkeyup instead :

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="processText(this)" />
```

Comment: +1 My opinion is this: if one key event type fails, try the other two.

Answer (score 0):

try onkeyup

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onkeyup.asp

Josh

Answer (score 0):

If `onkeyup` is too late for your needs, you'll need to look at the key code of the event and then do something with the character that may or may not be added to the text box. Take a look at the [DOM event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) or at the way [jQuery handles it](http://docs.jquery.com/Events) or the way [Prototype handles it](http://prototypejs.org/api/event).